# Python/Pandas - Long to Wide/ or Pivot or Stack/Unstack

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I would like to reshape data from long to wide. Especially columns [SAP Version, FY, Period, value]

What I have tried so far:

df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index(['Project No_left','Name','SBU Name','Reporting Level 1','Reporting Level 2','Reporting Level 3'])
Current DF:

Project No_left Name|   Reporting Level 1|  Reporting Level 2|  Reporting Level 3|  SAP Version|    FY| Period| value|
0-01214 Project A|  IP| NI| FS| 0|  2020|   Oct|    1939.92|
0-01214 Project A|  IP| NI| FS| 63| 2020|   Oct|    1939.92|
0-01214 Project A|  IP| NI| FS| 64| 2020|   Oct|    1939.92|
0-01214 Project A|  IP| NI| FS| 65| 2020|   Oct|    1939.92|
0-01214 Project A|  IP| NI| FS| 0|  2020|   Nov|    9052.96|
0-01214 Project A|  IP| NI| FS| 63| 2020|   Nov|    9052.96|
0-01032 Project B|  IP| AR| PO| 0|  2021|   Jul|    27842.5|
0-01032 Project B|  IP| AR| PO| 0|  2021|   Jul|    30000|
0-01032 Project B|  IP| AR| PO| 63| 2021|   Jul|    672500|
0-01032 Project B|  IP| AR| PO| 64| 2021|   Jul|    27842.5|
0-01032 Project B|  IP| AR| PO| 64| 2021|   Jul|    50000|
0-01032 Project B|  IP| AR| PO| 0|  2021|   Aug|    27842.5|
0-01032 Project B|  IP| AR| PO| 0|  2021|   Aug|    50000|
0-01032 Project B|  IP| AR| PO| 63| 2021|   Aug|    297500|
0-01032 Project B|  IP| AR| PO| 64| 2021|   Aug|    27842.5|
Expected DF:

+------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Project No_left| |   Name|    | Reporting Level 1  | Reporting Level 2| | Reporting Level 3| |  0|   |  63|  |  64|  |  65|  |  0|   |  63|  |  64|  |  65|  |
+------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Project No_left| | Name|      | Reporting Level 1  | Reporting Level 2| | Reporting Level 3| | 2020| | 2020| | 2020| | 2020| | 2021| | 2021| | 2021| | 2021| |
| Project No_left| | Name|      | Reporting Level 1| | Reporting Level 2| | Reporting Level 3| | Jul|  | Aug|  | Oct|  | Nov|  | Jul|  | Aug|  | Oct|  | Nov|  |
| 0-01214|         | Project A| | IP|                | NI|                | FS|                |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 0-01032|         | Project B| | IP|                | AR|                | PO|                |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
+------------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
can someone also tell me how to create a table to paste, i have tried this https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ but doesn't work properly :(

Pasting a picture as well to explain the outcome better. Thanksenter image description here

Comment: @jezrael - Thanks for the link but I couldnt find an answer that matches my requirement

Comment: Use `pivot_table`, index and columns by list by your columns names.

Comment: tried this, doesnt work - 
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Project No_left','Name','SBU Name','Reporting Level 1','Reporting Level 2','Reporting Level 3'],values=["value"],aggfunc=np.sum)
Where do i specify the columns that i want to transform to  wide like 'SAP Version', 'FY','Period' ?

Comment: pd.pivot_table(df,index=['Project No_left','Name','SBU Name','Reporting Level 1','Reporting Level 2','Reporting Level 3'],columns = ['SAP Version', 'Period','FY'], values=["value"],aggfunc=np.sum)